# How to get email body text and attachments using mimemessage class in java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime, mime-message

In my SMTP server code, I have a MimeMessage instance that I want to use for extracting the incoming mailbody(mail text) and mail attachments. To do this, I use the below implementation on client and server sides. However, I am only able to retrieve mail attachments. The code somehow detects CustomerEngineer.ahmet thing two times and none of them contains the mail body which is : "This is a message body".  I can retrieve the image though.

In my java mail client, I created a mail with the following schema:

```
try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));

        // Set Subject
        message.setSubject("Hi JAXenter");

        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        messageBodyPart.setText("This is a message body");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\CustomerEngineer.png")));
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("CustomerEngineer.ahmet");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        message.setContent(multipart);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

On my server side I use the following logic:

```
 MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, data);

public void seperateBodyAndAttachments(MimeMessage message) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    String mimeType = message.getContentType();
    Date dt = new Date();

    if (message.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        System.out.println("this containst a text file");
    }  else if (message.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) message.getContent();
        int idx = 0;
        int count = mp.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart part = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            String name = part.getDataHandler().getName();
            if (part.isMimeType("text/*")) {
                if (name == null) {
                    name = "text-" + (++idx) + ".txt";
                }
                System.out.println(name);
            } else {
                if (name == null) {
                    name = "attachment-" + (++idx);
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\resources\\DevEnvironmentConfigFile\\" + name));
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                part.getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
                bos.close();
            }
        }
    } else if (message.isMimeType("message/rfc822")) {
        // Not implemented
    } else {
        Object o = message.getContent();
        if (o instanceof String) {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\downloads\\"  + "text.txt"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write((String)o);
            bw.close();
        } else if (o instanceof InputStream) {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\downloads\\"  +"message.dat"));
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            message.getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
            bos.close();
        } else {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\downloads\\"  +"unknown.txt"));
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write((String)o);
            bw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure about your email structure. But be aware that multiparts can be nested - so you'll have to go all the way down in your search for the body. And with mutlipart/alternative, there might be more than one body.

In your case, you could be looking at

```
multipart/mixed
  multipart/alternative
    text/plain
    text/html
attachment
```

kind of structure. So the first multipart really does not include the body.
Consider this code:

```
public void seperateBodyAndAttachments(MimeMessage mm) throws MessagingException, IOException {
   String mimeType = message.getContentType();
   System.out.println("Message is a " + mimeType);  
   Object content = mm.getContent();
   if(content instanceof String) {
     System.out.println("Body: " + content);
   } else if(content instanceof MimeMultipart) {                
     MimeMultipart multi = (MimeMultipart)content;
     System.out.println("We have a "+ multi.getContentType());              
     for(int i = 0; i < multi.getCount(); ++i) {
        BodyPart bo = multi.getBodyPart(i);
        System.out.println("Content "+i+" is a " + bo.getContentType());
        //Now that body part could again be a MimeMultipart...
        Object bodyContent = bo.getContent();
        //possibly build a recurion here -> the logic is the same as for mm.getContent() above
      }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Some other content: " + content.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

In your case, the confusion comes from adding body-part twice:

```
    // This is the object created
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setText("This is a message body");

    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // you add a reference to this object into the multipart
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\CustomerEngineer.png")));

    //you CHANGE THE CONTENTS of the object to now contain your attachment
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName("CustomerEngineer.ahmet");

    //and add it a second time.
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Maybe try this for sending:

```
        // Set Subject
        message.setSubject("Hi JAXenter");


        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
        //Add Text Part         
        BodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textBodyPart.setContent("This is a message body", "text/plain");
        multipart.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);

        //Add attachment
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir").concat("\\src\\main\\java\\emailrelayserver\\CustomerEngineer.png")));
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("CustomerEngineer.ahmet");
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        //Set this as message content
        message.setContent(multipart);



        //This will show you internal structure of your message! D
        message.saveChanges();
        message.writeTo(System.out);

        Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: Hi Jan, oh wow thank you for that I didn't think that way. I go through the logic you constructed but it still doesn't click for me somehow :/ when I try this logic you suggest I get this output

 : Message is a multipart/mixed; 
 boundary="----=_Part_0_1072408673.1592314025145"
We have a multipart/mixed; 
 boundary="----=_Part_0_1072408673.1592314025145"
Content 0 is a application/octet-stream; name=CustomerEngineer.ahmet
Content 1 is a application/octet-stream; name=CustomerEngineer.ahmet

Comment: So somehow it is only able to retrieve attachments but on the client side above I added  messageBodyPart.setText("This is a message body") though;. ugh so annoying :D

Comment: Ah! You're reusing the same Body part! I'll add that to the answer

Comment: Hi Jan, first of all I'm truly thankful that you took your time to help me out. I tried this final solution but it still doesn't work for me. I've spent like almost the whole day long for this somehow can't get it working. In your updated answer, in the last part you say A simple -> then you share two lines of code, does that mean that I should delete all from the client side and use this? Also, I created a recursive part in the area where you say, now I get the output of : "Some other content: com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream" ughh I'm about to go crazy. thank you so much tho..

Comment: I added a larger part of the new sending code. Your initial code for retrieving the mail will probably work once the sending is fixed. But then it will only work for exactly these simple messages with plain-text body and attachments

Comment: Wow.. absolutely brain draining.. thank you so much I was able to understand it  and it works finally.. I really appreciate that Jan.

Comment: @Jan Thank you. Not only your codes but also your instructive explanation is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to extract a `MimeBodyPart` from a `MimeMessage`. It was trickier than I thought but I ended up robbing these 2 methods from [BouncyCastle](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/SMIMEGenerator.java#L124)

```
 /**
 * extract an appropriate body part from the passed in MimeMessage
 */
protected MimeBodyPart makeContentBodyPart(
    MimeMessage message)
    throws SMIMEException
{
    MimeBodyPart content = new MimeBodyPart();
    //
    // add the headers to the body part.
    //
    try
    {
        message.removeHeader("Message-Id");
        message.removeHeader("Mime-Version");

        // JavaMail has a habit of reparsing some content types, if the bodypart is
        // a multipart it might be signed, we rebuild the body part using the raw input stream for the message.
        try
        {
            if (message.getContent() instanceof Multipart)
            {
                content.setContent(message.getRawInputStream(), message.getContentType());
                extractHeaders(content, message);
                return content;
            }
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            // fall back to usual method below
        }
        content.setContent(message.getContent(), message.getContentType());
        content.setDataHandler(message.getDataHandler());
        extractHeaders(content, message);
    }
    catch (MessagingException e)
    {
        throw new SMIMEException("exception saving message state.", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        throw new SMIMEException("exception getting message content.", e);
    }

    return content;
}

private void extractHeaders(MimeBodyPart content, MimeMessage message)
    throws MessagingException
{
    Enumeration e = message.getAllHeaders();

    while (e.hasMoreElements())
    {
        Header hdr = (Header)e.nextElement();
        content.addHeader(hdr.getName(), hdr.getValue());
    }
}
```